# Eclipse SVN: How to recommit after failed commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

#### Problem

So, the repository I am trying to commit 50 files into has some pre-commit-hooks in place, of which I failed one.

#### Question

Is there a way to commit the same files again quickly, without having to select them one by one in the tedious Team -> Commit dialogue, e.g. by a hidden buffer or even a staging area like Git has?

#### My tools

- Eclipse Version: Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
- Subclipse 4.2.4

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.  The Eclipse Synchronize view does have a changesets feature you can use to manually put your changes into changesets and you can then commit the changeset.  If you are using Eclipse Mylyn this can be somewhat automated by following the Mylyn workflow.  That is about it though.